# Product is not adding in cart 'Django Administration'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm  unable to add the product in cart. I want to see the product is adding to cart or not. but the process is not happening. I'm using Django as backend, PostgresSQL as DB and HTML, CSS and Javascript as backend.

The Codes Goes here:

**views.py**

*`PRODUCT DETAIL`*

```
class product_detail(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        product_detail = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'detailpage/productdetail.html', {'product_detail':product_detail})
```

*`ADD TO CART`*

```
def addProduct(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    product_cart = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    Cart(user=user, product=product_cart).save
    return render(request, 'cart/addtocart.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('product_detail/<int:pk>', views.product_detail.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
    path('addProduct/', views.addProduct, name ='addProduct'),
]
```

**productdetail.html**

```
...
<form action="/addProduct"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{product_detail.id}}" id="product_id">   
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button> 
</form>
...
```

**models.py**

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**url pattern in address bar after hitting add button**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/addProduct/?product_id=2342
```

But after this also the product is not adding in Django cart
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the `save()` method.

```
def addProduct(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    product_cart = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    Cart(user=user, product=product_cart).save()
    return render(request, 'cart/addtocart.html')
```

Comment: how this small mistake I can't see???? Thank you for helping